# io.Pipe with WriteAtBuffer

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I would like to download and upload a file to aws s3 using streaming.
I wished to use io.Pipe but I can't because the downloader struct

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Downloader.Download

uses a "WriterAt" interface. and io.Pipe provides an io.Writer
I didnt succeed using the regular GetObject because it creates it downloads the object and doesn't receive a writer 
any solution for that?

thanks.

Comment: `Downloader` was designed to do concurrent download / upload, it can't work with a single `io.Writer`, so you can't stream with that. Here's an example that can be used to stream to / from S3: [copy files to / from s3](https://gist.github.com/howeyc/5021940)

Comment: Looks like this can be done disabling concurrency on the Downloader and adding a fake "WriterAt" just to satisfy the interface. Here a [post](https://dev.to/flowup/using-io-reader-io-writer-in-go-to-stream-data-3i7b) that details the main steps to get this to work.